# Comparison of int values in an if statement

Tags: c++, c, comparison

I had a question in my test paper in which we had to compare the values of int type variables. The first thought that came to my mind was that it was missing the && operator but i am not sure.

```
int a=2, b=2, c=2;
if(a==b==c)
{
    printf("hello");
}
```

I have a doubt, will the above statement will execute or not in c or c++? Can i have the reason as well.
Thank You

Comment: have you tried compiling it? or trying it out yourself?

Comment: `a==b==c` valid in some programing language for example Python, `a==b==c` same as `a==b and b==c`

Comment: What do comparison are you supposed to perform?

Comment: @AhmedMasud: That, sadly, will compile even though it will not give the expected result. Now, make the initialization `int a=1,b=1,c=1;` and it will compile and *seem* to work

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It will execute but with what I believe unexpected results to you.

One of the `==` will evaluate to a boolean value, which will then be converted to an `int` and then the second comparison will be performed, comparing an `int` to either `1` or `0`.

The correct statement is `a==b && b==c`.

For example:

```
3 == 3 == 3
```

evaluates to

```
true == 3
1 == 3
false
```

Comment: int this line `a==b==c` we can not be sure whether the evaluation will go from right to left or from left ro right? it's undefined?

Comment: @AlexandruBarbarosie my guess would be that the order is undefined.

Comment: @AlexandruBarbarosie because `==` is left-to-right associative, the first one will be executed first.

Comment: @Kninnug it's defined (inferred from the language syntax)

Comment: Just to be clear, the order in which the comparisons are executed is well defined, the order in which the operators are evaluated isn't specified. If those were expressions - i.e. `f() == g()`, it's not mandated that `f` is executed before `g`.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore hehe, I've seen so much Undefined Behaviour in C I expected it here as well. Seems I was wrong.

Answer (score 2):

```
a==b==c
```

is equivalent to

```
(a == b) ==  c
```

The result of `a == b` is `1` (if true) or `0` (if false), so it will probably not achieve what you expect.

Use `a == b && b == c` to check if the value of the three objects are equal.

Answer (score 0):

a == b == c is a comparison between c and result of a==b (1 or 0) operation.

Answer (score -1):

use `a==b&&b==c`. 
the condition `a==b==c` is equivalent to `(a==b)==c` which will provide the required result iff c==1, else the code will fail.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore:  In that case the result is true of c == 0.  When implicitly or explicitly cast to an integer, a boolean expression has values 0 (false) or 1 (true)

Comment: I know, I was pointing out that "which will provide the required result iff c==1" is wrong.